# Cant send more than 12 radio and checkbox option in form action mailto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button, mailto

I have this code like survey form with radio buttons and checkboxes. I try to fill in this form with all options, but the form `mailto` action doesn't perform if I select more than 12 radio & check boxes (total) in the entire page.

It takes all input as plain text and it operates if I select less than 12 radio buttons and checkboxes. I need the user to allow maximum selection and then send the data via mail. I don't know `JavaAPIMail` servlet so trying via form action `mailto`.

```
<section>

  <form action="MAILTO:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">                                                 
    <div class="title1">


      <ol class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item"> heading 1 :  
          <div>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="1" value="J">j</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="1" value="K">K</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="1" value="L">L</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="1" value="M">M</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="1" value="N">N</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="1" value="O">O</label>
          </div>
        </li>                       
        <li class="list-group-item"> Heading 2 :   
          <div class="form-row">
            <textarea name ="Head2:" placeholder ="Type Here" id ="H"></textarea>
          </div> 
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item"> Heading 3 : (you can select more than one option)    
          <div>
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="A:" class="ipad CCBOX" value="ipad">iPad</label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="A:" class="web CCBOX" value="web">Web</label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="A:" class="other CCBOX" value="other">other</label> 
          </div>
        </li>                           

        <li class="list-group-item"> Heading 4:  
          <div>                          
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="B" value="Daily">Daily</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="B" value="Weekly">Weekly</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="B" value="Biweekly">Biweekly</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="B" value="Monthly">Monthly</label>
          </div>
        </li>    




      </ol>

      <span id="web"><h3><b>Web</b></h3>

        <ol class="list-group" >
          <li class="list-group-item"> Heading 6: 
            <div>

              <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="C" value="Easy">Easy</label>
              <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="C" value="Neither easy nor difficult">Neither easy nor difficult</label>
              <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="C" value="Difficult">Difficult</label>
            </div>
          </li>                       

          <li class="list-group-item"> Heading 7: 

            <div class="form-row">
              <textarea name = "Q :" placeholder = "Type Here" id = "comment-good" ></textarea>
            </div>
          </li>                           
          <li class="list-group-item"> Heading 8:

            <div class="form-row">
              <textarea name = "W" placeholder = "Type Here" id = "comment-lack" ></textarea>
            </div>
          </li>                           
          <li class="list-group-item"> Heading 9

            <div class="form-row">
              <textarea name = "E" placeholder = "Suggestions" id = "comment-sugg"></textarea>
            </div>
          </li>

        </ol></span>

      <span id="ipad"><h3><b>ipad</b></h3>

        <ol class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item"> Heading 9  
            <div>

              <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="R" value="ipad Easy">Easy</label>
              <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="R" value="ipad Neither easy nor difficult">Neither easy nor difficult </label>
              <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="R" value="ipad Difficult">Difficult</label>
            </div>
          </li>                       

          <li class="list-group-item"> Heading 10
            <div class="form-row">
              <textarea name = "T" placeholder = "Type Here" id = "comment-goodipad"></textarea>
            </div>
          </li>                           
          <li class="list-group-item"> Heading 11
            <div class="form-row">
              <textarea name = "Y: " placeholder = "Type Here" id = "comment-lackipad" ></textarea>
            </div>
          </li>                           
          <li class="list-group-item"> Heading 12
            <div class="form-row">
              <textarea name = "U " placeholder = "Suggestions" id = "comment-suggipad" ></textarea>
            </div>
          </li>

        </ol></span>



      <span id="other"><h3><b>Other</b></h3>

        <ol class="list-group">

          <li class="list-group-item"> Heading 13 
            <div class="form-row">
              <textarea name = "I" placeholder = "Type Here" id = "comment-asuse" ></textarea>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item"> O
            <div>      
              <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="S" value="Easy">Easy</label>
              <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="S" value="Neither Easy nor difficult">Neither Easy nor difficult</label>
              <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="S" value="Difficult">Difficult</label>
            </div>
          </li>                           
          <li class="list-group-item"> Heading 14 :
            <div>
              <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Z" value="Yes">Yes</label>
              <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Z" class="csgo view" value="No">No</label>
            </div>
          </li>                           
          <li class="list-group-item excel" > Heading 15
            <div class="form-row">
              <textarea name = "X" placeholder = "Type Here" id = "comment-lackasd" ></textarea>
            </div>
          </li>                           
          <li class="list-group-item"> Heading 16:
            <div class="form-row">
              <textarea name = "V" placeholder = "Suggestions" id = "comment-suggasd" ></textarea>
            </div>
          </li>

        </ol></span>



      <h3><b>Scope</b></h3>

      <ol class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item"> Heading 17
          <div>

            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="F" value="Most of the times">Most of the times</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="F" value="Occasionally">Occasionally  </label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="F" value="Doesn't meet my requirements">
              Doesn't meet my requirements</label>
          </div>
        </li>                       
        <li class="list-group-item"> Heading 18:    
          <div>
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="d :"  value="D">D</label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="d :"  value="S">S</label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="d :"  value="C">C</label> 
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="d :"  value="M">M</label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="d :"  value="R">R</label>


          </div>

        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item"> Heading 19
          <div class="form-row">
            <textarea name = "hi:" placeholder = "Type Here" id = "comment-l" ></textarea>
          </div>
        </li>                           

        <li class="list-group-item"> Heading 20
          <div class="form-row">
            <textarea name = "hi2:" placeholder = "Suggestions" id = "comment-s" ></textarea>
          </div>
        </li>

      </ol>

      <h3><b>Overall Experience</b></h3>

      <ol class="list-group">

        <li class="list-group-item"> Heading 21:
          <div>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="H" value="Likely">Likely</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="H" value="Not-Sure">Not Sure</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="H" value="Unlikely">Unlikely</label>
          </div>
        </li>                           
        <li class="list-group-item"> Heading 22:  
          <div>   
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="G" value="Satisfied">Satisfied</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="G" value="Neutral">Neutral</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="G" value="Dissatisfied">Dissatisfied</label>
          </div> 
        </li>                           
        <li class="list-group-item"> Heading 24:
          <div>  
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="..." value="Size">Size</label> 
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="..." value="Competition">Competition</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="..." value="Mix of both">Mix of both</label>
          </div>
        </li>                           


        <li class="list-group-item"> Please provide your overall satisfaction:  
          <input id="input-2c" class="rating" min="0" max="5" step="0.5" data-size="sm" name="rating" data-symbol="&#xf005;" data-glyphicon="false" data-rating-class="rating-fa">

        </li>                      


      </ol>


      <!-- form submission -->
      <div class="wrapper">
        <input type="submit"  value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">


      </div>
      </form>
    </div>

</section>

</div>
</div>
</div>


</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.CCBOX').click(function () {

    $('#other').hide();
    $('#web').hide();
    $('#ipad').hide();

    if($(".ipad:checked").length === 1 ){
      $('#ipad').show();

    }
    if($(".web:checked").length === 1 ){
      $('#web').show();

    }
    if($(".other:checked").length === 1 ){
      $('#other').show();

    }
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('input[name="Z"]').on('click', function() {
      if ($(this).val() == 'No') {
        $('.excel').show();
      }
      else {
        $('.excel').hide();
      }
    });
  });

</script>
</html>
```

The problem that I am facing is when I click send button with all options selected, the mailto doesn't function. But if I select few number of radio buttons and checkboxes (maximum 12) the mail function operates. Please help me with where i have to make changes.

Comment: What operating system are you testing with? What email client? Lots of people now use webmail instead of desktop mail, for those users, this form will NOT work at all. So, you really need to figure out how to send the email through an API or server script. You could try this https://sendgrid.com or this https://www.mailgun.com/.

Comment: i am using Windows 8.1 OS and using form tag attribute action mailto , method post in html5.

Comment: Have you noticed if it happens when checking/unchecking any specific radio/box? A few of them have incorrect names (`d :`, `...`, `1`), but I don't know if that could be causing the issue

Comment: yes clicking is working fine

Comment: I checked the field names and they all work (despite unorthodox naming convention). Actually, the entire form works for me on OS X 10.11 using Mac Mail client. I think this could be a limitation of the operating system or email client. And again: you will have a large part of your target audience that literally will NOT be able to use this if they exclusively rely on webmail as opposed to an email client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I check everything and submit, I get an email with this in the body:

```
1=O
Head2:=
A:=ipad
A:=web
A:=other
B=Monthly
C=Difficult
Q :=
W=
E=
R=ipad Difficult
T=
Y: =
U =
I=
S=Difficult
Z=No
X=
V=
F=Doesn't meet my requirements
d :=D
d :=S
d :=C
d :=M
d :=R
hi:=
hi2:=
H=Unlikely
G=Dissatisfied
...=Mix of both
rating=
```

So, clearly, it's working for me. That's why I think it's an os or mail client issue.

Here it is with ALL text areas and text fields using values:

```
1=O
Head2:=
A:=ipad
A:=web
A:=other
B=Monthly
C=Difficult
Q :=value of Q :
W=value of W
E=value of E
R=ipad Difficult
T=value of T
Y: =value of Y: 
U =value of U 
I=value of I
S=Difficult
Z=No
X=value of X
V=value of V
F=Doesn't meet my requirements
d :=D
d :=S
d :=C
d :=M
d :=R
hi:=value of hi:
hi2:=value of hi2:
H=Unlikely
G=Dissatisfied
...=Mix of both
rating=Satisfaction value
```

Comment: hmm thanks i ll try with JAVA API mail servlet..  a link if you could send here would really help me out. thanks a lot Alain. :)

Comment: After looking a little, this is the simplest API I could find: https://formspree.io/ All you have to do is replace the "action" param of your form and they will process the form and email it to you. There are lots of advanced options too. You can pass special fields (as hidden fields) to include info like where you want it to send. ex: <input type="hidden" name="email" value="where@YouWantTheEmail.sent">

Comment: No problem Jay- can you accept my answer and let me know if it was helpful (using the up arrow)?